# testing framework for OWL ontologies

Tags: owl, protege

Is there a testing framework or tool or Protege's plugin for functional testing of OWL ontologies? e.g. to check presence or absence of some axioms in an onology,
to apply some test facts to the ontology and analyse new axioms obtained as a result.

Comment: Rdfunit is the only main testing framework widely accepted

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you, given an ontology you want to figure out

1. whether the stated axioms are correct and
2. whether there are any missing axioms.

(1) [OntoComP](https://github.com/julianmendez/ontocomp) is a plugin for Protege 4.x.  Given an ontology it will, by asking the user questions, either add counter examples or add additional axioms to the ontology. You can read more on this [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220853939_OntoComP_A_Protege_Plugin_for_Completing_OWL_Ontologies).

(2) Scenario testing for OWL ontologies defines a method via which you can setup "scenarios" to test that your ontology adheres to functional requirements. This is an approach I have defined in my MSc [dissertation](https://henrietteharmse.com/downloads/) and which we have used successfully to validate complex functional requirements for a hotel management group.

(3) You can use the [OWL API](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi) to test whether the required axioms hold:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLDataFactory dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(ontologyFileIRI);
OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new ReasonerFactory();
OWLReasoner reasoner = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(ontology);

OWLClass classA = dataFactory.getOWLClass(ontologyIRI + "#A");
OWLClass classD = dataFactory.getOWLClass(ontologyIRI + "#D");
OWLAxiom dSubclassOfA = dataFactory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(classD, classA);

reasoner.isConsistent();
System.out.println("D subclass of A = " + reasoner.isEntailed(dSubclassOfA));
```

The complete example code for this you can find [here](https://github.com/henrietteharmse/henrietteharmse/tree/master/blog/tutorial/owlapi/source/entailments).

Comment: The second option seems to be a quite interesting & detailed work. For me it is a challenge to deal with things like 'SubClassOf:(c min k Thing) and (c max l Thing), they are too hard to reason, because of the open world assumption :)...

Comment: However, I need simpler means, i.e. a way to repeatedly test ontologies. For example, it is expected, some test set of axioms produces another set of axioms after reasoning.. So, I need a tool to automatically apply the test set and check presence of the reasoned set.

Comment: @geeknet I also found the `SubClassOf:(c min k Thing)` difficult to think about initially, but accepting that this is just the UML representation, did eventually give me a foot hold into ontologies.

Comment: @geeknet I am not aware of a framework that does what you want, but you could in principle use the OWL API and write some code that can test whether specific inferences hold.

Comment: @geeknet Added OWL API option to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a challenge to apply testing procedures (functional tests) to a core (i.e. OWL2 driven knowledge base) of an ontology based application.

You can start with mentioned above:

-RDFUnit (https://github.com/AKSW/RDFUnit), but it seems to be very SPARQL specific.

Also things exist like:

-evOWLuator (https://github.com/sisinflab-swot/evowluator).
It is Python based, current version is 0.1.1, and they declare the support for ontology classification, consistency and 'matchmaking' reasoning tasks.

-Scone (https://bitbucket.org/malefort/scone/src/default/). It is quite perspective because allows usage of a controlled natural language, however is still in an early development stage.

And some research efforts are too.

-Again you are free to dive in DIY with OWL API.